# Combinatorial expression for all ternary strings that don't have consecutive 1's and 2's

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is: Find $C_n$, the number of all ternary strings (length $n≥0$) that don't have consecutive 1's and 2's, using combinatorics.

Any tips or advices?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "don't have consecutive $1$s and $2$s"? Do you mean we want to rule out just sub-sequences of just $1$s and sub-sequences of just $2$s e.g. $11111$ or $22222222$ or do we also want to rule out mixtures e.g. $1211121112$?

Comment: @ColmBhandal 01012021210 - valid string, 01110201012 - not valid.

Comment: Ah, that's a pity. I had calculated the answer to the other question, which is I believe $3^\frac{\lfloor n + 1\rfloor}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\tau=t_1t_2\ldots t_n$ is a valid string of length $n$. The zeroes in $\tau$ (if any) divide $\tau$ into blocks of non-zero characters. A block must alternate $1$s and $2$s, so once you know whether its first character is a $1$ or a $2$, you know the whole block. In particular, for each $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ there are exactly two possible blocks of length $\ell$.

Counting the gaps before $t_1$ and after $t_n$, there are $n+1$ gaps between characters of $\tau$. We can number these gaps $0$ through $n$ from left to right. (This means that the number of each gap is simply the number of characters of $\tau$ preceding that gap.) Each block on non-zero characters is defined by three numbers: the position of the gap immediately before its first element, the position of the gap immediately after its last element, and its first characters. For instance, if $n=10$ and $\tau=0121002101$, the blocks are $121$, $21$, and $1$. The first is defined by the gaps $1$ and $4$ and the initial character $1$; the second by the gaps $6$ and $8$ and the initial character $2$; and the third by the gaps $9$ and $10$ and the initial character $1$.

If $\tau$ has $k$ blocks, there are $\binom{n+1}{2k}$ ways to choose $k$ pairs of gaps to bound the blocks, and each block can start with $1$ or with $2$, so there are altogether $\binom{n+1}{2k}2^k$ valid strings of length $n$ having $k$ blocks. Summing over $k$, we see that there are

$$\sum_k\binom{n+1}{2k}2^k$$

valid strings of length $n$. (There’s no need to specify the range for $k$, since only finitely many terms are non-zero, and those correspond to the possible numbers of blocks.)

---

It’s also not hard to derive a nice recurrence for $C_n$. Let $a_n$ be the number of valid strings of length $n$ that end in $1$, $b_n$ the number that end in $2$, and $d_n$ the number that end in $0$; clearly $$C_n=a_n+b_n+d_n\;.$$ If a valid string of length $n$ ends in $1$, removing the $1$ must leave a valid string of length $n-1$ ending in $2$ or $0$. Conversely, a valid string of length $n-1$ ending in $2$ or $0$ can be extended to a valid string of length $n$ ending in $1$. Thus, $a_n=b_{n-1}+d_{n-1}$. Similarly, $b_n=a_{n-1}+d_{n-1}$. A valid string of length $n$ ending in $0$, on the other hand, can be the extension of *any* valid string of length $n-1$, so $d_n=C_{n-1}$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
C_n&=a_n+b_n+d_n\\
&=b_{n-1}+d_{n-1}+a_{n-1}+d_{n-1}+C_{n-1}\\
&=2C_{n-1}+d_{n-1}\\
&=2C_{n-1}+C_{n-2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the initial conditions are clearly $C_0=1$ and $C_1=3$. This recurrence is very easily solved by any of the standard techniques.

Comment: Thank you, the first part is exactly what I was looking for. I found the sum, however, could not explain it combinatorially.

Comment: @I.Vajs: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, the characteristic polynomial of the following adjacency matrix:
$$ P = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
is the same as the characteristic polynomial of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, with $a_n$ accounting for the number of strings with $n$ characters fulfilling the given properties. Since the roots of $x^3-x^2-3x-1$ are $-1$ and $1\pm\sqrt{2}$, we have:
$$ a_n = A\cdot(1-\sqrt{2})^n + B\cdot (1+\sqrt{2})^n + C(-1)^n $$
and the constants $A,B,C$ can be found by imposing that $a_1=3, a_2=7, a_3=17$.

That leads to:

> $$ a_n = \frac{1}{2}\left((1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for help, however I already have this recurrence relation. I now need to write it down using combinatorial expression (using sum maybe? I have no idea).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/602702/298209 Like here, the part with sum.

Comment: @I.Vajs: Well, with a combinatorial approach, you may start with a string (having length $\leq n$) with alternating $1$s and $2$s and insert zeroes somewhere. That leads to a sum of weighted binomial coefficients that ultimately leads to the same expression related with Pell numbers.

Comment: thank you, this helped a bit, however, could you be a bit more more specific? We didn't have Pell numbers in class so I don't think I can reference to them in my homework.

Comment: That is not my problem, I think I already gave you a hand. Please try to put some effort on your own, any mathematical activity is pointless otherwise.

Comment: @I.Vajs: You can take Jack's expression, expand it using the binomial formula, and see that the $\sqrt{2}$'s disappear (they have to, since $a_n$ is rational).

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $A(n)$, $A_0(n)$, $A_{\ne0}(n)$ the number of all admissible strings of length $n$, the number of admissible strings ending with $0$, and the number of admissible strings ending with $1$ or $2$, respectively. Then $A(n)=A_0(n)+A_{\ne0}(n)$, and therefore
$$A(n+2)=2A_{\ne0}(n+1)+3A_0(n+1)=2A(n+1)+A_0(n+1)=2A(n+1)+A(n)\ .$$
The characteristic equation of the recurrence for the $A(n)$ is $\lambda^2-2\lambda-1=0$, with the solutions $\lambda_1=1+\sqrt{2}$, $\lambda_2=1-\sqrt{2}$. It follows that
$$A(n)=c_1(1+\sqrt{2})^n+c_2(1-\sqrt{2})^n\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $c_1$ and $c_2$ have to be determined from
$$A(1)=3, \quad A(2)=7\ .$$
One obtains
$$c_1={1+\sqrt{2}\over2},\quad c_2={1-\sqrt{2}\over2}\ .$$
Plugging this into $(1)$ we see that we can write
$$A(n)={\rm round}\left({1\over2}(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}\right)\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
I don't think that this can be written as a "one strike" combinatorial expression.

Comment: The explicit expression can be rewritten using the binomial theorem as a sum of the form $\sum_na_n(\sqrt{2})^n$; the terms for odd $n$ then cancel out (as they have to, since the result is integral!) and the final result can be written as a sum of rational terms from this, analagous to the formula $F_n=2^{1-n}\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2} 5^k{n\choose 2k+1}$ that can be derived from Binet's formula.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Actually using binomial theorem to write it as a sum makes sense, great! At least I have a way now to write it down without recursion. I still think there is a way to explain it combinatorially, though.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*.

> We consider the set $ \mathcal{V}^{\star}$ of words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1,2\}$$ and the set $B=\{11,22\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ being  the number of searched words of length $n$.

According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $f(s)$  is
\begin{align*}
f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=3$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ the *weight-numerator* with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[11])+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])
\end{align*}
We calculate according to the paper
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[11])&=-s^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[11])s\\
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])&=-s^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])s\\
\end{align*}
and get
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[11])=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])=-\frac{s^2}{1+s}
\end{align*}

$$ $$

> It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-3s+2\frac{s^2}{1+s}}\\
> &=\frac{1+s}{1-2s-s^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Partial fraction decomposition and expansion of $f(s)$ results in
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{1-(1+\sqrt{2})s}+\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{1-(1-\sqrt{2})s}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}\right)s^n\\
> &=1+3s+7s^2+17s^3+41s^4+99s^5+\mathcal{O}(s^6)
> \end{align*}