# Generating series for ternary strings without 000 and not ending with 0

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

I would like to find a formula for $T_n$, the number of ternary strings of length $n$ so that they do not contain three consecutive zeroes, and they do not end with $0$ as well. I can find a recurrence relation for $T_n$, however I wonder if we can express $T_n$ as a coefficient of a generating series. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a look at these highly related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602593/find-recurrence-relation-for-ternary-strings-that-dont-have-substrings-00-01-a?rq=1; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050496/recurrence-relation-to-find-ternary-strings-that-do-not-contains-3-consecutives?rq=1. You should try to apply the methods from there, then update this question with details of your attempts, if you are still stuck. If you're not stuck, post your own answer and then accept it! `:D`

Comment: @SamOT I already read the questions you commented, but both of them are about recurrence relation which I can manage. I just don't know how to use these ideas to get generating series for $T_n$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you said you _can_ find a recurrence. My mistake! I don't have any particular insight for you, sorry `:'(` I gave you a +1, anyway, as it's a good question. I hope you find assistance! `:)`

Comment: You should show your recurrence relation for $T_n$.

Comment: @mapping Look at slides 14 - 23 in  https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf

Comment: @mapping you did not say anything , is there anywhere you did not understand in my solution

Comment: @Bulbasaur sorry for my late reply. I am still reading the Goulden-Jackson-Cluster method you mentioned to understand your answer. Anw, I compared your final answer with the one given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050496/recurrence-relation-to-find-ternary-strings-that-do-not-contains-3-consecutives?rq=1 and found that they are not the same. Following that link, the recurrence relation for $T_n$ should be $T_n=3T_{n-1}-2T_{n-4}$ since $T_n=2a_{n-1}$ where $a_n$ is the number of ternary strings of length $n$ without three consecutive 0's. I wonder if I made mistake somewhere.

Comment: @mapping in my solution we find for $(n-1)$ and the last digit can be either one or two , your question has extra restriction ,

Comment: @Bulbasaur oops! You are right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mapping you are welcome ! When i look at comments , i realize that my answer is alittle bit advanced , but i hope you understand what i write there. If there is any place you do not understand in my answer , you can ask it. Have a nice day..

Comment: @mapping did my answer help you ? if so , can you acept it ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you work over recurrence relations , and you are willing to learn. Hence , i will share a very powerful method with you. You can handle nearly all recurrence relation problems with it. Our method is *[Goulden -Jackson- Cluster Method](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* . I put that link for you , you can read it to learn detaily.

Lets turn to our question. We can claim that $\color{red}{|}$the number of strings that do not have three consecutive zeros$\color{red}{|}$ = $\color{blue}{|}$ the number of strings that do not have three consecutive zeros and end up with $0$$\color{blue}{|}$ + $\color{red}{|}$ the number of strings that do not have three consecutive zeros and end up with $1$ $\color{red}{|}$ + $\color{red}{|}$ the number of strings that do not have three consecutive zeros and end up with $2$ $\color{red}{|}$.

Here , we are looking for $\color{red}{|}$ the number of strings that do not have three consecutive zeros and end up with $1$ $\color{red}{|}$ + $\color{red}{|}$ the number of strings that do not have three consecutive zeros and end up with $2$ $\color{red}{|}$. Right ?

We can see that the number of strings of length $n$ that do not have three consecutive zeros and end up with $1$ is equal to the number of strings of length $(n-1)$ that do not have three consecutive zeros. It is also valid for the string that ends up with $2$.

Now , it is the time for using our powerful method. We will find a generating function and convert it into a sequence of length $(n-1)$.

Lets first calculate for the string end up with $1$ and do not have $3$ consecutive zeros.We said that it is equal to the number of string of length $n-1$ that does not have three consecutive zeros.

We know that our alphabet consists of $3$ elements such as $V=\{0,1,2\}$ , and our bad word is $\{000\}$.

According to the paper $(p.7)$ the generating function $A(z)$ is $$A(z)=\frac{1}{1-dz - \text{weight}(c)}$$

with $d=|V|=3$, the size of the alphabet and $C$ the weight-numerator of bad words with $$\text{weight(c)}= \text{weight}([000])$$

$$\text{weight}([000])= -z^3 - (z^2 +z)\text{weight}([000])$$

$$\text{A(z)}= \frac{1}{1-3z + \frac{z^3}{1+z+z^2}}$$

$$\text{A(z)}= \frac{1+z+z^2}{1-2z-2z^2 -2z^3}$$

We also obtain the same result for the string end up with $2$. Then , the sum of them will give us the generating function for them.Namely , $$\frac{2+2z+2z^2}{1-2z-2z^2 -2z^3}$$

Now , we should convert it into recurrence relation by We recall if a generating function has a representation as rational function of the form
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}
\end{align*}
with $P(z), Q(z)$ polynomials, $\deg Q=q>\deg P$ and
\begin{align*}
Q(z)=1+\alpha_1 z+\alpha_2 z^2+\cdots + \alpha_q z^q
\end{align*} then the coefficients $a_n$ follow the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
a_{n+q}+\alpha_1 a_{n+q-1}+\alpha_2 a_{n+q-2}+\cdots +\alpha_q a_{n}=0\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
\end{align*}

Then , our recurrence relation is $$a_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3}+2a_{n-4}$$

*[Calculation via wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%282%2B2x%2B2x%5E2%29%2F+%281-2x-2x%5E2+-2x%5E3%29)*

It means that for $n=4$ , there are $52$ such strings , for $n=5$ , there are $152$ such strings , for $n=15$ , the answer is $6843168$ ,so on..

Comment: Please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/) and my answer.  I am attempting to make that question a **complete** reference for all similar questions.  This way, any similar future question can be immediately closed/deleted as a duplicate, with the OP given a link to this (reference question).  However, for completeness, the question lacks a **separate, very detailed** answer that uses generating functions.  ...see next comment

Comment: The idea is that a bright 18 year old, should be able to understand the answer.  This is the approach that my answer *attempted*, which is why it is necessarily long-winded.  I am wondering if you would be interested in providing such a highly detailed, fully justified, step by step answer to the question, that only involves generating functions.  For generating function theory that is too lengthy to include in your answer, hopefully, you would provide a link to an online reference that is *dumbed down* enough so that whatever theorems that you use are clearly proven in the reference.

Comment: @Bulbasaur: There seems to be an erroneous shift by one somewhere. There are 52 valid strings of length $4$ as you noted, but $52=[z^3](2A(z))$ is the coefficient of $z^3$ in your generating function.

Comment: @epi163sqrt it is because i  calculated for length $(n-1)$ , you can read it paragraph $4$ in my answer.. coefficient of $z^3$ in legth $(n-1)$ is equal to coefficient of $z^4$ in length $n$

Comment: @user2661923 you are right  it would be good if i gave more detailed answer , but the method is so long to give full explanation. As i mentioned in my answer , i gave the solution for those who know about the method , thats why i  added a link

Comment: @Bulbasaur: I see. In this case you might want to clearly state the relationship of $a_n$ with $T_n$ to improve readability. The recurrence relation needs initial value settings in order to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

We can describe the set of valid strings as the strings built from the alphabet $V=\{0,1,2\}$ which contain at most one or two consecutive $0$'s and do not end with a $0$.

**A regex:** We consider strings

- starting with zero or more $1$s or $2$s:$\qquad\quad(1|2)^*$
- followed by zero or more occurrences of $0$ or $00$ each followed by one or more $1$s or $2$s: $$(0(1|2)^+|00(1|2)^+)^*$$

> We obtain a regular expression describing all valid words:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(1|2)^*(0(1|2)^+|00(1|2)^+)^*}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Note these words end with either $1$ or $2$ but not with $0$ as required.

**Generating function: $T(z)$:**

> The regular expression (1) generates all valid words in a *unique* manner. In such cases we can use it to derive a generating function $$\color{blue}{T(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n z^n}$$ with
> $T_n$ giving the number of valid words of length $n$.

In order to do so all we need to know is the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* since the $star$ operator
\begin{align*}
a^*&=\left(\varepsilon|a|a^2|a^3|\cdots\right)&\text{ translates to } &1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-z}\\
(a|b)^*&=\left(\varepsilon|(a|b)|(a|b)^2|(a|b)^3|\cdots\right)&\text{ translates to } &1+2z+4z^2+8z^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-2z}\\
\end{align*}

Accordingly $a^+=aa^*$ translates to $\frac{z}{1-z}$ and alternatives like $(\varepsilon|a|aa)$ can be written as $1+z+z^2$.

> We obtain from (1) by translating the regular expression in the language of generating functions (and by mixing up somewhat the symbolic to provide some intermediate steps)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(1|2)^*(0(1|2)^+|00(1|2)^+)^*}
> &\longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1-2z}\left(\left.\frac{2z^2}{1-2z}\right|\frac{2z^3}{1-2z}\right)^*\\
> &\longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1-2z}\left(\frac{2z^2+2z^3}{1-2z}\right)^*\\
> &\longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1-2z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{2z^2+2z^3}{1-2z}}\\
> &\quad\quad\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-2z-2z^2-2z^3}}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude: The number of valid words is given by the generating function $T(z)$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{T(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-2z-2z^2-2z^3}}\tag{2}\\
> &=1+2z+6z^2+18z^3+\color{blue}{52}z^4+152z^5+444z^6+1\,296z^7\cdots
> \end{align*}

The expansion was done with the help of Wolfram Alpha. We see that e.g. the number of valid words of length $4$ is $\color{blue}{52}$.

**Coefficients $T_n$:**

> We can now calculate $T_n$ from $T(z)$. In order to do so it's convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. We obtain from (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{T_n}&=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-2z\left(1+z+z^2\right)}\\
> &=[z^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(2z)^k\left(1+z+z^2\right)^k\tag{3.1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k[z^{n-k}]\left(1+z(1+z)\right)^k\tag{3.2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n2^{k}[z^{n-k}]\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}z^l(1+z)^{l}\tag{3.3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n2^{k}\sum_{l=0}^{\min\{k,n-k\}}\binom{k}{l}[z^{n-k-l}](1+z)^{k}\tag{3.4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^n2^{k}\sum_{l=0}^{\min\{k,n-k\}}\binom{k}{l}\binom{k-l}{n-k-l}}\tag{3.5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (3.2) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ and set the upper limit of the sum to $n$ since other values do not contribute.
- In (3.3) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (3.4) we use again the rule as in (3.2) and restrict the upper limit since the *coefficient of* operator has non-negative exponents of $z$ only.
- In (3.5) we select the coefficient of $[z^{n-k-l}]$.

**Example $T_4$:**

We use (3.5) to calculate exemplarily $T_4$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{T_4}&=\sum_{k=0}^{4}2^k\sum_{l=0}^{\min\{k,4-k\}}\binom{k}{l}\binom{l}{4-k-l}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^0\binom{0}{l}\binom{l}{4-l}+2\sum_{l=0}^1\binom{1}{l}\binom{l}{3-l}+4\sum_{l=0}^2\binom{2}{l}\binom{l}{2-l}\\
&\qquad\quad+8\sum_{l=0}^1\binom{3}{l}\binom{l}{1-l}+16\sum_{l=0}^0\binom{4}{l}\binom{0}{0-l}\\
&=0+0+4\left(\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}+\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{0}\right)+8\binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{0}+16\binom{4}{0}\binom{0}{0}\\
&=0+0+4\cdot3+8\cdot3+16\cdot1\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=52}\\
\end{align*}
as expected.